# how to use update() method instead of add() in SharePoint on Job Timer using visual studio c#

Tags: visual-studio

i have created a solution in SharePoint from visual studio C#. I want to create a Job Timer so i have created a c# class too. but now I'm adding a new row to task list but what i want really to do is to update a specific row not to add new one. the code belongs as follow:

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
{
SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
SPList taskList = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["Tasks"];
SPListItem newTask = taskList.Items.Add();
newTask["Title"] = "New Task" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
newTask.Update();
}
```

I repeat again instead of add new row i want to update. Could anyone help me please.

Comment: Well, taskList.Items is a collection, so you will have to somehow identify the item you want to update. Exactly how do you need to do that? Which item are you targeting?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist  on my project I have a column named "Ditet" and that column i want to update for all rows. I don't know how to achieve this any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the same column for ALL items in the list, then the following code should work

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
{
    SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
    SPList taskList = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["Tasks"];
    SPListItemCollection taskListItems = taskList.Items;
    int increment = 2;

    foreach (SPListItem taskItem in taskListItems)
    {
        // Insert you logic here to get the value you want to insert in the "Ditet" column
        // If you want to increase the previous value you can do the following
        int oldDitetValue = Convert.ToInt32(taskItem["Ditet"].ToString());
        taskItem["Ditet"] = oldDitetValue + increment;
        taskItem.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: than you so much this worked perfectly. thank you so much. But now i want
      `taskItem["Ditet"] =2;` Ditet to be equal 2 and for everytime the value of ["Ditet"] to be 4, 6, 8, 10..etc to sum the value of 2 + 2 do you understand me?

Comment: @NderonHyseni Please check the updates I added to the code. You save the old value from the column and then you just add 2 to it.

Comment: Ziga yes sir but look, i have made a JobTimer that executes every 15 minutes. I set the value for `["Ditet"] = 2;` after 15 minutes I want that value to be 4 again after 15 min to be 6 and after again after minutes to be 8 and so on. Do you understand now me?

Comment: `taskList["Ditet"] = 2 + convert.Toint32(taskList["Ditet"]) + 2` this is what i wanted to do but anyway thank you soooo much i dont know what to do if you did not tell me! thank you so much sun i love you haha :P keep going brother keep posting you answers